# making a soundboard in android studio but the app keep crashing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i was making a soundboard with android studio (without Soundpool)
and before to put the sound in i was making sure that the app work..but it keep crashing and i don't know why.maybe i'm just overthinking and it's so simple but i can't understand where the problem is and how can i fix it

error:

```
    Process: com.example.soundboard, PID: 21283
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.soundboard/com.example.soundboard.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at com.example.soundboard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

mainactivity

```
package com.example.soundboard;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Toolbar toolbar;

   final String[] soundList = {"lissandrone" };




   RecyclerView SoundView;
   final SoundboardRecyclerAdapter SoundAdapter = new SoundboardRecyclerAdapter(soundList);
   RecyclerView.LayoutManager SoundLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.soundboard_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SoundView = findViewById(R.id.soundboardRecyclerView);
        SoundLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);

        SoundView.setLayoutManager(SoundLayoutManager);

        SoundView.setAdapter(SoundAdapter);

    }
}
```

recycler adapter

```
 package com.example.soundboard;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class SoundboardRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SoundboardRecyclerAdapter.SoundboardViewHolder>{



    private final String[] soundObjects;

    public SoundboardRecyclerAdapter(String[] soundObjects){

        this.soundObjects = soundObjects;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SoundboardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sound_item,null);
        return new SoundboardViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SoundboardViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.itemTextView.setText(soundObjects [position]);

    }
     @Override
    public  int getItemCount() {
        return soundObjects.length;
     }

     public static class SoundboardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
     {
         final TextView itemTextView;
         public SoundboardViewHolder(View itemView) {
             super(itemView);

             itemTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
         }
     }

}
```

sound_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagineViewItem"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"
        android:src="@drawable/lissliss"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imagineViewItem"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/professor"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imagineViewItem" />
```

toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/black">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

mainactivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:id="@+id/activity_soundboard">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/soundboard_toolbar"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/soundboardRecyclerView"
        android:layout_below="@id/soundboard_toolbar"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your ConstraintLayout is a ConstraintLayout. Not a Toolbar

Comment: i knew it was so easy ahah , sorry and thanks